# Delete a specific item menu when I deactivate my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, menus, customization

When I activate my plugin ([`register_activation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)), I add a new specific page and a corresponding item menu in the custom menu. No problem here.

When I deactivate my plugin ([`register_deactivation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook)), I delete the specific page but I don't know how to delete the corresponding item menu from the custom menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress automatically handles that if you force delete the page instead of thrashing it.
The following function takes a parameter to force delete ->
[`wp_delete_post( $postid, $force_delete )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post)

Comment: Setting $force_delete to "true" is the solution. Thank you Joshua:)